# Can [water] burn?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burnination

[water](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water)

We currently have 18 questions tagged [water]. Going through these, I fail to see the value of the tag. No-one is following the tag and I would be surprised if we had any "water experts" within the context of SF & Fantasy.

This tag is irrelevant and may lead to other similarly irrelevant tags being added. Therefore, I propose to burn [water](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water).

Comment: Yes yes yes \o/

Comment: I like to consider myself an expert on water, being more than 60% it myself.

Comment: SQB used a Fire move against a Water type. It's not very effective...

Comment: @Jenayah I'd argue that it's very effective, with +8/-0.

Comment: Ah yes, making water burn, a very Scifi-y concept.

Comment: Nice tag wiki. _"Water is a colourless, transparent, odourless, liquid comprised primarily of two hydrogen atoms and one oxygen atom."_

Comment: @MrLister Water won't burn in a fluorine environment? (I'm not arguing the point, haven't had a chemistry class since 11th grade.)

Comment: It will produce strong acid, oxygen gas, and ozone, the latter of which can feed fires. It may produce an explosive precipate. But it won't burn.

Comment: Iirc, in a pure oxygen atmosphere, even things that are soaking wet will burn. But I don't know if the water itself burns. Given what a stable molecule H2O is, I rather doubt it.

Comment: @MikeStone [chlorine trifluoride](https://blogs.sciencemag.org/pipeline/archives/2008/02/26/sand_wont_save_you_this_time). "It is also hypergolic with such things as cloth, wood, and test engineers, not to mention asbestos, sand, and water-with which it reacts explosively."

Comment: @zabeus That's better than most tag wikis...

Comment: @SQB Your link says that "Ignition" is out of print, but if you're interested (and it's a great read) you can find it [here](https://library.sciencemadness.org/library/books/ignition.pdf)

Comment: @DavidW thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the tag should indeed be deleted. Mainly agreeing with what you have stated in your question. "Water" does not add any value as tag, even to a story-id question. Likewise we do not and should not have tags like "air, fire, dirt" they add no relevance to science fiction or fantasy elements in helping define a question.

Answer (score 10):

[water](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water) [earth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/earth) [fire](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fire) [air](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air)

Long ago, the four tags lived together in harmony. Then everything changed when the BurniNation attacked.

Only the mods, masters of all tags, could fix them. And when SFF needed them most, they didn't vanish.

A couple of days passed, and my fellow users and I bought up the tag mess, with the [water](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water) tag. And although the mods' [water](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water)-burninating skills are great, they have a lot to learn before they can save [earth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/earth).

But I believe, that mods can save SFF.

---

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

<sub>Joke aside, while we're on burnination we really don't need [earth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/earth)...</sub>

Comment: And yes I know we don't have `[air]` and `[fire]` but after reading Skooba's answer I couldn't resist to make the joke. :p

Comment: [tag:earth] has been sent hurtling towards the sun and has burnt up.